# Why does this RegEx fail when a space is added to end of character sequence?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

Here's some code that I've got in my javascript to detect whether or not a string is a Right-To-Left (RTL) script:

```
is_right_to_left : function (text) {

      /*
       * Right-to-left Unicode blocks for modern scripts are:
       *
       * Consecutive range of the main letters:
       * U+0590  to U+05FF  - Hebrew
       * U+0600  to U+06FF  - Arabic
       * U+0700  to U+074F  - Syriac
       * U+0750  to U+077F  - Arabic Supplement
       * U+0780  to U+07BF  - Thaana
       * U+07C0  to U+07FF  - N'Ko
       * U+0800  to U+083F  - Samaritan
       *
       * Arabic Extended:
       * U+08A0  to U+08FF  - Arabic Extended-A
       *
       * Consecutive presentation forms:
       * U+FB1D  to U+FB4F  - Hebrew presentation forms
       * U+FB50  to U+FDFF  - Arabic presentation forms A
       *
       * More Arabic presentation forms:
       * U+FE70  to U+FEFF  - Arabic presentation forms B
       */

        var ltrChars        = 'A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8\u0300-\u0590\u0800-\u1FFF'+'\u2C00-\uFB1C\uFDFE-\uFE6F\uFEFD-\uFFFF',
            rtlChars        = '\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC',
            rtlDirCheck     = new RegExp('^[^'+ltrChars+']*['+rtlChars+']');

        return rtlDirCheck.test(text);

    }
```

This is working up to all the tests I've done.  However, if I add a space to some sequences of characters from an RTL script, it fails the test.  For example, if I have `ﺮﺳﻷﺍ` the function correctly detects that the string is RTL.  However, if I add a trailing space then the function reports that it is NOT an RTL script.  What is wrong with my RegEx?  I want to be sure that a space won't throw it off.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to double escape ``\``s in the `\u` notation inside a RegExp constructor. To support trailing space, just add `\\s*` at the end. I have tried your code and it [handles spaces](https://jsfiddle.net/7mjv7kzu/).

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for the suggestion.  I will try it, but ultimately I don't want a space anywhere to throw it off, not just at the end.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: As we can see with the JSFiddle from Wiktor Stribiżew, your original posted function still returns `true` even with spaces anywhere between and at the end. You would have to provide a concrete example where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want a space anywhere to throw it off, not just at the end. How can I achieve that?

You want to use a negative look ahead operator.

```js
function is_right_to_left (text) {

      /*
       * Right-to-left Unicode blocks for modern scripts are:
       *
       * Consecutive range of the main letters:
       * U+0590  to U+05FF  - Hebrew
       * U+0600  to U+06FF  - Arabic
       * U+0700  to U+074F  - Syriac
       * U+0750  to U+077F  - Arabic Supplement
       * U+0780  to U+07BF  - Thaana
       * U+07C0  to U+07FF  - N'Ko
       * U+0800  to U+083F  - Samaritan
       *
       * Arabic Extended:
       * U+08A0  to U+08FF  - Arabic Extended-A
       *
       * Consecutive presentation forms:
       * U+FB1D  to U+FB4F  - Hebrew presentation forms
       * U+FB50  to U+FDFF  - Arabic presentation forms A
       *
       * More Arabic presentation forms:
       * U+FE70  to U+FEFF  - Arabic presentation forms B
       */

        var ltrChars        = 'A-Za-z\\u00C0-\\u00D6\\u00D8-\\u00F6\\u00F8-\\u02B8\\u0300-\\u0590\\u0800-\\u1FFF'+'\\u2C00-\\uFB1C\\uFDFE-\\uFE6F\\uFEFD-\\uFFFF',
            rtlChars        = '\\u0591-\\u07FF\\uFB1D-\\uFDFD\\uFE70-\\uFEFC',
            rtlDirCheck     = new RegExp('^(?!.*['+ltrChars+'\\s]+.*)['+rtlChars+']$');

        return rtlDirCheck.test(text);

    }
    alert(is_right_to_left("ﺮﺳﻷ ﺍ"));
```

Here is a quick description of the regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: when I run the code snippet it returns "false" in the alert box.  The function is for "Is_right_to_left" and your test string is an RTL string.  Shouldn't it return true?

Comment: @ariestav The test string is an RTL string. However, there is a space down in the string. This is why the code snippet returns false since space are not allowed anywhere in the string (negative look ahead operator).

Comment: I meant to say that I want the RegEx to still consider a string with only RTL chars and spaces as an RTL string.  In some cases, I'm finding that if there is a space trailing or within a sequence of RTL chars (i.e. arabic), the RegEx still reports the string as being LTR.